# for_each through a object in Terraform 0.12

Tags: terraform, terraform-template-file, terraform-modules

I want to call terraform module in the next way:

```
module "database_role" {
 source = "modules/roles"

 project_id = "testid"
 role_name = "testrole"

 actions = {
   action: ["ENABLE_PROFILER", "DROP_DATABASE"]
   database_name: "test_db"
 }
```

roles module definition i created is:

```
resource "mongodbatlas_custom_db_role" "custom_role" {
  project_id = var.project_id
  role_name  = var.role_name

  dynamic "actions" {
    for_each = [for item in [var.actions] : item]
      content {
        actions {
          action = lookup(actions.value, "action")

          resources {
            cluster = "false"
            database_name = lookup(actions.value, "database_name")
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

as result i want to see actions properly generated:

```
 actions {
   action = "ENABLE_PROFILER"
   resources {
     cluster         = "false"
     database_name   = "test_db"
   }
 }


 actions {
   action = "DROP_DATABASE"
   resources {
     cluster         = "false"
     database_name   = "test_db"
   }
 }
```

I'm getting error: The given value is not suitable for child module variable "actions".
What i'm doing wrong in module dynamic resource? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [flatten](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/flatten.html) function could be used here.

I've below `actions` local var::

```
locals {
  actions = {
    action = ["ENABLE_PROFILER", "DROP_DATABASE"]
    database_name = "test_db"
  }
}
```

Now, I'll flatten based on the size of `local.actions["action"]` to achieve the desired result. Once, I get the flattened list, I would loop through the list to create dynamic blocks.

```
resource "mongodbatlas_custom_db_role" "custom_role" {
  project_id = "xxx-xxx"
  role_name  = "yyy-yyy"

  dynamic "actions" {
    for_each = flatten([
      for item in range(length(local.actions["action"])): {
        act = local.actions["action"][item]
        db_name = local.actions.database_name
      }
     ])
     content {
       action = actions.value.act
       resources {
         cluster = "false"
         database_name = actions.value.db_name
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

This would produce the required number of blocks I like::

```
Harshas-MBP:mongo harshavmb$ terraform plan
Refreshing Terraform state in-memory prior to plan...
The refreshed state will be used to calculate this plan, but will not be
persisted to local or remote state storage.


------------------------------------------------------------------------

An execution plan has been generated and is shown below.
Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  + create

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # mongodbatlas_custom_db_role.custom_role will be created
  + resource "mongodbatlas_custom_db_role" "custom_role" {
      + id         = (known after apply)
      + project_id = "xxx-xxx"
      + role_name  = "yyy-yyy"

      + actions {
          + action = "ENABLE_PROFILER"

          + resources {
              + cluster       = false
              + database_name = "test_db"
            }
        }
      + actions {
          + action = "DROP_DATABASE"

          + resources {
              + cluster       = false
              + database_name = "test_db"
            }
        }
    }

Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.

------------------------------------------------------------------------

Note: You didn't specify an "-out" parameter to save this plan, so Terraform
can't guarantee that exactly these actions will be performed if
"terraform apply" is subsequently run.
```

This could be applied to create resources too. The key idea of working with nested or complicated loops is to flatten them into a list of resources or blocks, we create and then iterate through the flattened list with unique indexes as shown in above example.

Comment: thanks, how to make skipping dynamic actions if variable is empty or not set? Thanks

Comment: put a conditional operator to loop only when the length > 0. 
`length(local.actions["action"]) > 0 ? for item in range(length(local.actions["action"])): {
        act = local.actions["action"][item]
        db_name = local.actions.database_name
      } : {}`

something like this. syntax may be incorrect but you can try I think